# Multi-level perl hash

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash which looks like below when I use Dumper. I want to iterate over each level and print everything individually.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'TP144' => {
                          'LNDN CDR' => [
                                            'NAME   XYZ
                        FNAME   ABC
                        STATUS  MARIED
                        TEST   "THIS IS TEST"
                        TEMP!VALUE   0'
                                        ],
```

This is how it looks like: The value of L2 is itself an array.

```
$VAR1{L1}{L2}=>ARRAY
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Thanks Mat, I found the answer in that link. Here's how I did it.

```
foreach $L1 ( sort keys %VAR1 ) {
     print "$L1: { ";
     for $L2 ( sort keys %{ $VAR1{$L1} } ) {
         foreach  (@{$VAR1{$L1}{$L2}})
         {
             print $_."\n";
         }

     }
     print "}\n";
 }
```

Comment: @Mat Thanks that link helped me finding the right answer.

Comment: @Mardanian - that works, but be careful to only feed it identical data structures. It won't work for other structures.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest approach is to do so recursively.

- Check your input to the recursive sub.

  - If your input is a scalar, print
  - If your input is n arrayref, loop over each element and recursively print that element using your sub
  - If your input is a hashref, loop over each key and recursively print the value of that key using your sub.

DONE

Comment: If you have trouble implementing any of those 3 steps, please show what you tried and ask how to fix it.

Comment: I tried this: 


<pre><code>while(($key, $value) = each(%VAR1))
{
    @keyValues = split($;, $key);
    print "key = [", join(",", @keyValues), "] : value = [", $value, "]\n";
}</code></pre>


but I get below error: 


`key = [TP144] : value = [HASH(0x16b6478)]`

Comment: @Mardanian - have you read the answer? You need a recursive sub